# Why can't you use generic type parameters in constraints on type extensions?

Tags: generics, f#

I've recently been working on generating FFI code for TypeScript 0.9.1 definitions. I came across this issue...

This code:

```
    type 'T IList with
        member __.ConcatWith<'U when 'U :> 'T IList>(items : 'U) : 'T[] = failwith "not implemented"
```

Produces this type error:

> The type parameter 'T' is not defined.

**NOTE: This error only occurs inside type constraints section. Using the generic type parameter in other places (e.g., as a return type) works fine.**

However, if I define a type rather than a type extension it is fine. Unfortunately, I don't have this luxury. The extensions I define sometimes need to be in separate assemblies.

I am aware of the `[<Extension>]` attribute but I would like the extensions to be consumable from inside F# (for the FunScript project).

I could put the method in a `module`. However, the methods would be harder to discover. This isn't what I want.

I could use C#. However, then I wouldn't be able to add extension indexes and properties. Therefore, this isn't acceptable.

Are there any workarounds for this issue?

I'm thinking that I may have to lift out the type constraints. For example: `ConcatWith<'U when 'U :> 'T IList>(items : 'U)` would become: `ConcatWith(items : 'T IList)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Looks like you miss the 'T in the brackets. I mean, it should be ConcatWith<'T, 'U when 'U ...

Comment: @Gustavo No the type parameter should come from the type declaration `'T IList` or `IList<'T>`. Like I said, it works in most cases just not inside the constraints section inside a type extension. If it was a type definition rather than type extension it would work (i.e., not `type IList<'T> with` but `type IList<'T>() =`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me.

If the constraint that you actually need to express is the one in the sample here (`'U :> 'T IList`) then I think you can workaround it using `#IList<'T>` type (but that won't work for more complex constraints):

```
type 'T IList with
    member __.ConcatWith(items : #IList<'T>) : 'T[] = failwith "not implemented"
```

C# style extension methods using `Extension` are supported in F# 3.1 (both defining and consuming) so that might be another alternative, but it would mean relying on new version of F# (but perhaps that's not so bad, if there was an alternative way to write it using module function that would work in F# 3.0)